# C# (Web API) Multilayer (IOC) API Controller Return Type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, return-value

I am building an ASP Web API application and this time I thought I will go with the MVC pattern. I got along with most of the stuff, but there is one thing of which I am unsure. First of all my project consists of the following:

- Data Layer
- Business Layer
- Model Layer (just the model with the properties)
- Service Application (here are my controllers)

  every one of them in a separate project

Lets say I have the following controller

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    ISomeService _someBusiness;

    public TestController(ISomeService someBusiness)
    {
        _someBusiness = someBusiness;
    }

    public **SomeModelObject** GetModelObject(ind id)
    {
        return _someBusiness .GetSomeModelObject(id);
    }

}
```

Now my problem is the return value of `GetModelObject(int id)`. Here it says `SomeModelObject`. That implies that my Service application (or my controller) has to know everything about the model which is being used (so I dont see the point in defining it in a separate .dll). One way would be to define the model (precisely the get/set mothods) as an interface, but I think that it would be too much that every model class has an interface (mostly because, as I said, just the properties are being stored inside the model), and despite that I just does not feel right to build an interface for a class which only stores data. So, is there any generic response type which is being used in this case (even some completely different approach), or do I have to use my model classes (or may i just always use string and it is being converted to the appropriate format by the client) ?

Comment: I don't understand why you have a problem referencing the models layer dll from the service. That is quite a normal thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

There's a good reason to use an interface to hide the complexity of the model object. It holds data, sure. But it holds unnecessary data that is only meaningful to the data layer. Take this EF model:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Collection<TimeCard> TimeCards { get; set; }

    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
}
```

This is a fairy common EF model. It contains a surrogate key `Id`, and a foreign key `DepartmentId`. Those values are meaningless except for the database and, by extension, for entity framework. `EmployeeNumber` is the natural key which uniquely identifies the entity in the user's domain.

Outside of database access, you should really only deal with natural data values. You could do this by declaring yet another data-carrying class in the Business layer and perform mapping, or a better idea is to use an interface to hide all of the members that are not useful.

```
public interface IEmployee
{
    string EmployeeNumber { get; }
    string Name { get; set; }

    ICollection<ITimeCard> TimeCards { get; }
    IDepartment Department { get; set; }
}
```

Notice the lack of some setters in the interface. You'll never want to change the EmployeeNumber because that is the natural key for the entity. Likewise, you'll never assign a collection object to the `TimeCards` property. You'll only ever iterate over, add, or remove them.

Now your Employee class becomes

```
public class Employee : IEmployee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Collection<TimeCard> TimeCards { get; set; }
    ICollection<ITimeCard> IEmployee.TimeCards { get { return TimeCards; } }

    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
    IDepartment IEmployee.Department { get { return Department; } set { Department = value; } }
}
```

In your business layer and above, you'll only use variable of IEmployee, IDepartment, and ITimeCard. So you are exposing a tighter API to the higher layers, which is a good thing.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i will implement it like this and see if it fits my needs. And one more question. I have put all my interfaces into a separate project(Interfaces.dll). Is this the right approach or should i keep them with the actual layer (interfaces for the model layer should be inside modellayer.dll and so on)? Both of the approaches have their pro/cons but i have chosen the one where everything is in a separate project

Comment: It is better to put them in a separate project, but not vital. If everything is in one solution, it is easy enough to move them into a new project later on.

Comment: When i am using ISomeObject as the return type, i get the following exception in my browser: Type 'ModelLayer.SomeObject' with data contract name 'SomeObject:schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ModelLayer'; is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer. System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException Do i need to define some serialization inside the interface ?

Comment: The return type from what?

Comment: from my controller function. Something like this: public ISomeModelObject GetModelObject(ind id)
    {
        return _someBusiness.GetSomeModelObject(id);//return type or GetSomeModelObject is ISomeModelObject
    }                                                                                          When i use SomeObject it works fine. Even if i use ISomeObject and  do  "return (SomeObject)ISomeObject" it works fine. But when i just do "return ISomeObject" i get the error (but ISomeObject is being properly resolved, when i debug it i see that it is being provided with right values)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a generic approach at controller level:

```
public class BusinessController<T> : ApiController
{
    ISomeService _someBusiness;

    public TestController(ISomeService someBusiness)
    {
        _someBusiness = someBusiness;
    }

    public T GetModelObject(ind id)
    {
        return _someBusiness.GetSomeModelObject(id);
    }

}
```

Finally your controlers inherit from BusinessController instead of ApiController:

```
public class TestController : BusinessController<SomeModelObject>
{
}
```

You could also take advance of the templating to inject the right "ISomeService" by using an IoC container and a bootstrapper.

Comment: This is actually something i have never seen before. How does this whole dependency injection (especially if you have a lot of classes) influent performance ? Right now i have about 10 classes on which i am doint dependency injection(with Unity) and i wonder how that affects the performance (or does it just influence the initial launch of the application) ?

Comment: Dependency injection is a technic to improve mainaitability and architecture. It is the "D" in SOLID principles. Regarding performance, there is not a measurable penalty if you do the things properly. The overhead is on the "resolve" Ioc container method, that substitutes a regular "new". If you are not going to create thousands of objects and the object instantiacion time is not really criticall, you could rely on IoC without any concers.